# How to configure .env file when i am using mailgun with smpt in laravel 5.8?

Tags: laravel

> i have a free account of maiilgun.i want to send mail using mailgun
> with smtp credential.before i tested sending mail using normal
> processs without using mailgun.that time mail sending wokring
> properly.but now does not work when i am using smtp credention of
> mailgun in .env file.
>
> previous .env setttings

```
MAIL_MAILER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=rabby*****aman@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=&******&
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=rabby*****aman@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

> here is my present configuration of .env for using mailgun

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@sandbox38901c*********d87c6b5d4df6d.mailgun.org
MAIL_PASSWORD=fe8*******e24f75eff3fb4855-e687bab4-b140ef78
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=rabby****aduzzaman@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=sandbox38901c*****d5896ed87c6b5d4df6d.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_SECRET=baddc7ae051*****1c80a8c4a28-e687bab4-51fa7fd1
```

Comment: Let debug to send mail function is it working properly or not?

Comment: mail is working without using mailgun

Comment: Can you change use mailtrap?

Comment: no i have to use mailgun

Comment: "mail is working without using mailgun"
how do you confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

This all you need for laravel env.

(API)

```
MAIL_DRIVER    = mailgun
MAILGUN_DOMAIN = mg.YOUR_DOMAIN.com
MAILGUN_SECRET = YOUR_KEY_HERE
```

(SMTP)

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME={your mailgun username} 1 - "Default SMTP Login" on your mailgun Domains page
MAIL_PASSWORD={your mailgun password} 2 - "Default Password" on your mailgun Domains page
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

MAILGUN_DOMAIN={your mailgun domain} 3 - Your mailgun Domain name
MAILGUN_SECRET={your mailgun API Key} 4 - "API Key" on your mailgun Domains page
```

Comment: i am not using api.i am using smtp

Comment: ohh i see then. maybe you can try this.

MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME={your mailgun username} 1 - "Default SMTP Login" on your mailgun Domains page
MAIL_PASSWORD={your mailgun password} 2 - "Default Password" on your mailgun Domains page
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

MAILGUN_DOMAIN={your mailgun domain} 3 - Your mailgun Domain name
MAILGUN_SECRET={your mailgun API Key} 4 - "API Key" on your mailgun Domains page

Comment: how to get api keys?

Comment: when i clicing on API key i found private api key.Is it the same key?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mrabbani/33a6260ba52073a52cb5 -> i think this will help you

Comment: https://devdojo.com/devdojo/sending-emails-with-laravel-and-mailgun-> this is the full guide or tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

If all the credentials are set and you are getting errors, you should run `composer dump-autoload`.